# Question about how to put data in JSON format

Tags: json

Hello i have categories with answers data, e.g.:

- **Europe**: Germany, Austria, Hungary
- **Asia**: China, Japan, Cambodia

And I need to put it in json:

```js
{
"correctAnswers": {
  "category": {
    "name" : "Europe", 
    "categoryAnswers": ["Germany", "Austria", "Hungary"]
  }
 }
}
```

How i can add the second category Asia with answers?
I understand that my question is very simple and my suggested variant may be not optimal but i am total new in Json and haven't get the right answer in Google.

Comment: JSON is just a data structure format, essentially composed of any nesting you want of objects, arrays, and values.  All three of which are demonstrated in the data structure shown.  So the question really becomes... How do you *want* your data to be structured?  How is it intuitively structured and organized to you?  Can you define a data structure in pseudo-code?  Can you express that structure in JSON?  What have you tried and what isn't working as expected?

Comment: David I don't have any limitation i just want to store 2nd and more categories similar the first one. If the structure in my example isn't optimal it can be changed in any optimal way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{
    "correctAnswers": {
        "Europe": {
           "name": "Europe",
           "categoryAnswers": ["Germany", "Austria", "Hungary"]
         },
 
        "Asia": {
           "name": "Asia",
           "categoryAnswers": ["China", "Japan", "India"]
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: Wow, thanks, it seems to me that is exactly what i wanted. Answer will be accepted after 5 min.

Answer (score 2):

The data structure is all in the semantics of the data you're describing.  You keep using this word (in the question and comment(s)):

> categories

But your structure has this word:

> category

That's probably the difference you're looking for.  If `category` should represent *plurality* then I would imagine it should be an array:

```
{
  "correctAnswers": {
    "categories": [
      {
        "name" : "Europe", 
        "categoryAnswers": ["Germany", "Austria", "Hungary"]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Which would then allow you to add more "category" objects to that array:

```
{
  "correctAnswers": {
    "categories": [
      {
        "name" : "Europe", 
        "categoryAnswers": ["Germany", "Austria", "Hungary"]
      },
      {
        "name" : "Asia", 
        "categoryAnswers": ["China", "Japan", "Cambodia"]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Ultimately it's up to you and how you want to structure the data for the application.  The data structure is essentially an endlessly nestable series of:

- Arrays
- Objects
- Values

So if, semantically, the `correctAnswers` object should have a list of `category` objects, then semantically that list would be called `categories` and would be an array.  It's really up to the semantics of the data you're trying to describe in the structure.

Comment: i like this also, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can put something like this, if behind you want to gather it in some list of objects  :

```html
{
  "correctAnswers": {
    "categories": [
      {
        "category": {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "Europe",
          "categoryAnswers": ["Germany", "Austria", "Hungary"]
        }
      },
      {
        "category": {
          "id": 2,
          "name": "Asia",
          "categoryAnswers": ["China", "Japan", "Cambodia"]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```